# Laravel - Trazer Componente tipo SELECT JÁ SELECIONADO ao editar

Tags: laravel

Estou tentando trazer um select já selecionado conforme a informação que está gravada no banco. Porém estou tendo muita dificuldade. Vou deixar o código abaixo.

**Controler**

```
public function ListaUf()
{
    $ListaUf = Estado::all();
    return view(‘psicologo’,compact(‘ListaUf’));
}
```

**Rotas**

```
Route::get(’/psicologo/editar/{psi_codigo}’,‘ControladorMunicipioUf@ListaUf’);
```

**View**

```
<select>
    @foreach($ListaUf as $uf)  
        <option {{$psi->uf_codigo=={{$uf->uf_codigo}} ? 'selected':''}} value="{{$uf->uf_codigo}}">{{$uf->uf_estado}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Está dando algum erro? onde especificamente é a dificuldade?

Comment: eu modifiquei o código. ele está assim agora.

Comment: Tente trocar  `{{$psi->uf_codigo=={{$uf->uf_codigo}} ? 'selected':''}}` para `{{$psi->uf_codigo == $uf->uf_codigo ? 'selected' : ''}}`

Answer (score 0):

Se você está buscando um estado específico, use:

```
public function ListaUfEditar($id)
{   
   $ListaUf = Estado::find($id);
   return view('psicologo',compact('ListaUf'));

}
```

Ou você pode passar um array de ids para então retornar uma collection.

Para buscar todos os estados em uma collection para iterar na sua view use o método "all()" sem argumentos.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent